# PHP position of "." or EOL in a string - whichever is closer

Tags: php, string, strpos

I'm parsing a text and I need to find end of a sentence. There are not all senteces finishes with dot (.), some of them finishes with linebreak (PHP_EOL), for example chapter titles. I need to be able to find the end of a sentence after any given point of text.

Of course I can do:

```
$senteceEndswithDot = mb_strpos($content, ".", $randomPos+1, 'UTF8');
$senteceEndswithBreak = mb_strpos($content, PHP_EOL, $randomPos+1, 'UTF8');
```

and then compare those two numbers but is there any more elegant way to code this?

Comment: Regex would win in elegance. Efficiency? Probably not.

Comment: @rjdown For me regex would look better. Would that be also faster or not?

Comment: Note that PHP_EOL is platform dependent, so your code running on Windows where line endings are `\r\n` may have problems with files/content that only use `\n`.

Comment: @MarkH.good point. I will run this on Ubuntu Linux Server though

Comment: Drive-by-comment: I would use strpos instead of mb_strpos because finding a character offset into a multi-byte string runs in O(n) time whereas finding the byte offset in a string is O(1) time. The "." and EOL characters are the same in ASCII and UTF-8 so there is no functional difference between the two methods and running a O(n) operation repeatedly on a document with lots of sentences will kill your performance.